# Tinkerpop: select vertex which do not have path to vertex having a property

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, tinkergraph

In Tinkerpop, I want to select vertices which are not directly connected to vertices having property `foo` equal to `bar`

For ex:

```
Vertex user1 = graph.addVertex("vid","one");
Vertex user2 = graph.addVertex("vid","two");
Vertex user3 = graph.addVertex("vid","three");

Vertex tag1 = graph.addVertex("tagKey", "tagKey1");
Vertex tag2 = graph.addVertex("tagKey", "tagKey2");
Vertex tag3 = graph.addVertex("tagKey", "tagKey3");

user1.addEdge("user_tag", tag1);
user2.addEdge("user_tag", tag2);
user2.addEdge("user_tag", tag3);
```

In above test case I want to select all `user` vertices which are not connected to tag vertices with `tagKey` with value of `tagKey2`. Output should be 2 vertices `user3 , user 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query to fetch the Vertex those are not connected to tags.

```
g.V().hasLabel("Vertex").
    filter(
        not(outE().hasLabel('connected'))
        ).
    properties()
```

Query to add the Vertex data:

```
g.addV('Vertex').as('1').property(single, 'name', 'One').
  addV('Vertex').as('2').property(single, 'name', 'Two').
  addV('Vertex').as('3').property(single, 'name', 'Three').
  addV('Vertex').as('4').property(single, 'name', 'Four').
  addV('Tag').as('5').property(single, 'name', 'Key1').
  addV('Tag').as('6').property(single, 'name', 'Key2').
  addV('Tag').as('7').property(single, 'name', 'Key3').
  addE('connected').from('1').to('5').
  addE('connected').from('2').to('6').
  addE('connected').from('4').to('7')
```

Gremlify link: https://gremlify.com/f1muf12xhdv/2

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `not` and `where` steps:

```
g.V().hasLabel('User').
  not(where(out('user_tag').has('tagKey', 'tagKey2'))).
  valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)
```

example: https://gremlify.com/jybeipj4zjg